# Как взять значения всех полей внутри формы?

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток.
Какой есть алгоритм взятия всех значений полей и их имен внутри формы при помощи JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем-то основная идея в том, что нужно пройтись по всем элементам формы, доступ к оным нам предоставляет коллекция `FormElement.elements`, т.е. суть примерно такая:

```
function getFormHash( form ) {
  var inputs = form.elements, res = {};
  for( var i=-1; ++i < inputs.length; ) {
    var input = inputs[ i ];
    if( input.name && (input.type !== 'radio' || input.checked) ) {
      res[ input.name ] = input.value
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Код далек от идеала т.к., например, никак не обрабатывает множественные значения, был написан для демонстрации сути.

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: @Антон Мухин, как всегда - нет проблем :)

Comment: у jQuery есть хороший метод [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: Спасибо, но я без jQuery. Только native js, только хардкор!!! :)

Comment: @Антон, хоть кто то уважает натив как я...